# MySQL query with column of null values

Tags: python, mysql, null, tornado

I have this query:

```
 user = self.db.query("SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.name, n.network_id, n.perm \ 
FROM users as u LEFT OUTER JOIN nets_permissions as n \ 
ON u.id = n.user_id WHERE u.id!=%s", int(usr_id))
```

The column 'perm' (permission) is an int value, that can be a value like 1, 2, 3, ecc. or a null value. I want a query like this:

```
 user = self.db.query("SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.name, n.network_id, n.perm \
FROM users as u LEFT OUTER JOIN nets_permissions as n \
ON u.id = n.user_id WHERE u.id!=%s" AND n.perm!=3, int(usr_id))
```

So, I want delete from the query the records with perm=3.

I thinked that I can retrieve the id of the user with perm=3 in this way:

```
self.lock_tables("read", ['nets_permissions'])
        admin = self.db.query("SELECT user_id FROM nets_permissions \
                               WHERE network_id=%s AND perm=3", nid)
        self.unlock_tables()
```

and then I could write

```
 self.lock_tables("read", ['users as u', 'nets_permissions as n'])
   user = self.db.query("SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.name, n.network_id, n.perm \
FROM users as u LEFT OUTER JOIN nets_permissions as n \
ON u.id = n.user_id WHERE u.id!=%s AND u.id!=%s", int(usr_id), int(admin))
            self.unlock_tables()
```

But this doesn't work....

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.name, n.network_id, n.perm 
FROM users as u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN nets_permissions as n 
ON u.id = n.user_id 
AND n.perm<> 3 
WHERE u.id!=%s
```

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Give them time - there's a ten minute delay restriction, I think :)

Comment: No no I have to take 10 minute after I can accept the answer ;) thank you @podiluska